# Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual) for multiple expected values

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, assert

How can I assert that a variable satisfies any one of two values in Visual Studio's unit testing environment?

I've seen other testing frameworks do it like this:

```
Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("HomePage") | Is.Empty);
```

I'm not experienced with Visual Studio's unit testing environment.

Comment: Try `||` instead of `|`?  `|` is a bitwise OR and probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: The bitwise operation (|) comes directly from the sample, though I completely read over it (most definitely not an OR (||)!). This comes from NUnit and is supposed to be an "alternative" constraint assert, but I'm still not sure what the intention is, if not an OR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I think the sample line of code you typed contains an error, if you have no intention to perform a bitwise OR.

```
Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("HomePage") || Is.Empty);
```

Secondly, I suspect a misleading test here, since unit testing shall tests for one and only one specific scenario. So, if you assigned, for example, one value to a property, you expect this very value to be returned by its getter.

Third, here's how I would go for it, considering I might miss your point and you definitely need to test for either result.

```
Assert.IsTrue(string.Equals(result.ViewName, "HomePage") || string.Equals(result.ViewName, string.Empty));
```

On the other hand, I have never ever tested a scenario where I expected two different results from the same unit test. `Assert.That` might be good as well.